# Declare member function only on specific specialization of templated class

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a templated class to aid in compile time computation of physical quantities. It uses the extra template parameters (`std::ratio`) to ensure things like a `Length` can only be added to a `Length`, or that `Area` is a `Length` times a `Length`.

```
#include <ratio>

template <
  typename Length      = std::ratio<0>, // Meter
  typename Mass        = std::ratio<0>, // Kilogram
  typename Time        = std::ratio<0>, // Second
  typename Current     = std::ratio<0>, // Ampere
  typename Temperature = std::ratio<0>, // Kelvin
  typename Amount      = std::ratio<0>, // Mole
  typename Luminous    = std::ratio<0>  // Candela
>
class Quantity {
private:
  double value;
public:
  constexpr Quantity(double val) : value(val) {}

  Quantity &operator+=(Quantity const &that) {
    value += that.value;
    return *this;
  }

  // ...
};
```

But sometimes I want to convert back to a simple `double`, for interfacing with other stuff.

I could add a member function for the templated class that returns the internal `double` - or enables implicit (or explicit) conversion to `double` when a `double` is needed.

```
  constexpr double getValue() { return value; }
  constexpr operator double() { return value; }
```

However, I really only want this implicit conversion to happen when the "dimensions" of the quantity are all 0 (all template parameters are 0).

I could just *declare* the same member functions and only *define* the specialization that I want. But that still declares that the conversion exists for types that I don't ever want to  allow conversion from (you should divide by your desired units first). This makes my editor tell me it's ok but it won't link at compiletime.

Is there a way to declare member functions only on certain specializations?

Of note, I'm stuck on C++14 for now, otherwise I think an `if constexpr` could work...

Answer (score 1):

No, `if constexpr` cannot be used to provide for conditional definition of class methods. `if constexpr` belongs in some method or a function, so that needs to be declared before anything can be done with `if constexpr`, and your goal is to not even declare it in the first place.

There is no way to directly instantiate a class method only for certain specializations or template instances, however there's a common approach that comes pretty close: simulate an overload resolution failure.

Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct life {
    template<typename=
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value>::type>
    constexpr int answer()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    life<int> of_brian;

    std::cout << of_brian.answer() << std::endl; // Shows 42

    life<double> of_black_night;

    std::cout << of_black_night.answer() << std::endl; // Error
    return 0;
}
```

The template class effectively implements `answer()` only for its `int` instance. `gcc`'s error message, for attempting to invoke it from an undesirable instance of the template is:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘life<double>::answer()’

which is a pretty close facsimile for "this doesn't exist, pal".

This is logically equivalent to what you're attempting to do with your template, the only difference is that you need to check a bunch of template parameters, instead of just one.